# The coloration of the Kopet Dag Mountains

Tags: mountains

Why are the Kopet Dag Mountains (on the border between Iran and Turkmenistan) coloured much like the Bulgarian flag?

[image]

[[Link to satellite imagery in Google Maps](http://www.google.com/maps/place/37%C2%B032'56.1%22N+59%C2%B002'00.3%22E/@37.5489072,59.0159135,6061m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d37.548903!4d59.033423)]
(Location is 37.548903 North, 59.033423 East)

Comment: Do you have a latitude and longitude of the location you are viewing?

Comment: Of course: 37.548903,59.033423

Comment: I think the real question is why is the Bulgarian flag colored much like the Kopet Dag Mountains.